# How to input strings in a char array and how to print it out

Tags: c

This is my code, I'm traying to read a string from keyboard and store it in char "nombre" but at the time to print it only prints the first letter of each string

int main()
{

```
char nombre[10][50]={0};
float calificacion[10];
float promedio=0, calificacionAlta=0, calificacionBaja=100;
int opc, sobresaliente, deficiente;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno no. %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%s", nombre[i]);
}
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingresa la calificacion del alumno no. %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &calificacion[i]);
    promedio+=calificacion[i];
    if(calificacion[i]>calificacionAlta)
        sobresaliente=i;
    if(calificacion[i]<calificacionBaja)
        deficiente=i;
}
promedio/=10;
printf("Elige con que funcion quieres imprimir los datos\n");
printf("1.- For\n");
printf("2.- While\n");
printf("3.- Do While\n");
printf("4.- Salir\n");
scanf("%d", &opc);
switch(opc){
    case 1:
```

Here is the part where I'm trying to print the info of the array

```
        printf("Alumnos por encima del promedio\n");
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            if(calificacion[i]>promedio){
                printf("Nombre: %c\n", *nombre[i]);
                printf("Calificacion: %.2f\n", calificacion[i]);
            }
        }

        printf("Alumno sobre saliente\n");
        printf("Nombre: %c\n", *nombre[sobresaliente]);
        printf("Calificacion: %.2f\n", calificacion[sobresaliente]);
        printf("Alumno burro\n");
        printf("Nombre: %c\n", *nombre[deficiente]);
        printf("Calificacion: %.2f\n", calificacion[deficiente]);
        break;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `printf("Nombre: %c\n", *nombre[i]);` --> `printf("Nombre: %s\n",  nombre[i]);`

Comment: Thank you your answer was really helpful, just that simple